# Call composition ready of (edge animate) from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, adobe-edge

I have a problem in html5 edge animate. I have created an animation using edge animate. 
I would like to call composition ready of edge animate from outside. I tried calling using `$.Edge.registerCompositionReadyHandler( compId, handlerFn, options )` , But it gave error `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` . I am not able to solve this and  i did not find enough documentation about this. Can any one please help me.

my code looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
<title>Untitled</title>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime-->

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="teste1_edgePreload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="teste1_resize.js"></script> 
<style>
    .edgeLoad-EDGE-1429726 { visibility:hidden; }
</style>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime End-->

<script>
  $.Edge.registerCompositionReadyHandler("EDGE-1429726",scaleStage) //SCALE STAGE IS INSIDE THE JAVASCRIPT fn teste1_resize.js
function mover(){
      var stage = $.Edge.getComposition("EDGE-1429726").getStage();
      console.log($("#Stage").height());
      stage.mover();
 }
</script>

</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
<div id="Stage" class="EDGE-1429726">
  <input type="button" value="Mover" onClick="mover();">
</div>

</body>
```

Thanks in ADVANCE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Ena's help and little modification i was able to find an answer.

```
AdobeEdge.bootstrapCallback(function(compId) {
    AdobeEdge.Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, 'stage', 'document', 'compositionReady', function(sym, e){
        // composition is loaded, do stuff here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
$.Edge.registerCompositionReadyHandler
```

use

```
AdobeEdge.registerCompositionReadyHandler
```

Moreover, put your code inside this function:

```
AdobeEdge.bootstrapCallback(function(compId) {
    // Register your handlers here
});
```

So you are sure the stage is loaded and you can register handlers in it.

Comment: Hey, I already tried these some days back, but it did not work :(

Comment: Now i use javascript timeout unfortunately :(

Comment: Try to invert the order of the loading scripts:

<script type="text/javascript" src="teste1_resize.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="teste1_edgePreload.js"></script>

Then from inside Adobe Edge Animate, in the code window add the event Stage > compositionReady. In the code call your function:
scaleStage();

Comment: Hello Ena, I had done the way you told and it works. But, we dont want to mess with Edge Animate Code. We wanted to implement composite ready from outside.